# Firebase, OAuth, Elm

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-api, firebase-authentication, elm

I am trying to implement simple voting tool, SPA using Elm.
I would like to use Firebase for this.
I have found couple options how Elm could work with Firebase:

1. Some Elm packages but those are using native bindings.
2. Elm talking to JS using ports.
3. Elm using REST API.

I have chosen to go for option 3 and it works for me but only for me. I would like other user also have an access to this app.
I have enabled google as authentication provider and rules for my realtime database are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I am the owner of Firebase project and this Elm app works for me and I can see the results of GET and I can even send PATCH to vote.

However as mentioned above no one else can access data via my app and REST. First GET request gives back Unauthorized access but I can see new users logged in/registered in Firebase Console.

My application uses my API Key and access token is fetched, then access token is attached to the REST request (I tried both methods: Authorization, Bearer header and ?access_token=).
I have read Firebase samples and docs couple times but I am still missing something.

Is it possible to design this app the way I want?
What else shall be done to authorize REST request from other users?

Comment: I can't think of any particular reason that other users would be denied access. You'll need to post some code if you want us to help debug it.

Comment: You can place the '$uid' variable in your rules - it represents the id from the currently logged user. Using this you can crate sections in your database that are readable for specific users. You can read more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 1):

Like I stated in my question I had been missing something.
With the great help from Elm community on Slack I finally understood the missing piece.
This page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth mentiones two types of authentication.

1. Google OAuth2 access tokens
2. Firebase ID tokens

I have used the option 1 but I should use option 2 for my simple SPA.
Using Firebase SDK it is easy to fetch the token

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
```

that has to be attached to every HTTP request being sent to the Realtime Database on Firebase. Such token should be placed within query ?auth=

Using this token other users can get an access to my application.